# Area of Triangle and Diophantine Equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

We are given some arbitrary solution $(x_0, y_0)$ to $ax-by=1$ and another point $(b,a)$. We are asked to prove that the area of the triangle with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(b,a)$, and $(x_0, y_0)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$. I figured that I should use the equation for a right triangle, and apply some substitution as follows:

$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\sqrt{(b-x_0)^2+(a-y_0)^2}$

plugging in $x_0$ and $y_0$ in terms of the diophantine equation doesn't seem to cancel out any terms and the algebra is messy.

Comment: Have you learned an area formula for triangles in the plane given coordinates of their vertices, involving a determinant?

Comment: I have not.....

Comment: If all else fails, just resort to [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).

Answer (score 1):

The point $(x_0,y_0)$ lies on a line parallel to the opposite edge of the triangle. Therefore you can choose any point on this line and the area will always be the same!

So just choose the  point $(\frac{1}{a},0)$ and the triangle then has base $\frac{1}{a}$ and area $a$. It therefore has area $\frac{1}{2}\times a \times \frac{1}{a}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I'm not entirely confident I understand your initially statement. I'm having trouble visualizing that.

Comment: Both lines have gradient $a/b$ and are therefore parallel.

Comment: Yes, I had that in mind. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Let a base of a triangle be on a line $l$. The area of the triangle then depends only on the distance of the third point from $l$ and this is the same for all points on a line parallel to $l$.